# Does the definition of "mean"/"average" require the result to be in the domain set?

Tags: definition

If I have a function that calculates the mean value of a set of elements that is an arbitrary subset of some set $X$, does the mean, by definition, have to also be in $X$? (In other words, if the mean *can't* be in $X$, does that imply that "mean" cannot be defined for $X$?) If not, is there a counter example?

Example: If I can calculate the mean of a set of *floobles*, does the mean value also need to be a *flooble* for me to be able to claim that I can actually calculate the mean?

Edit - Possibly More Concrete Example: If I claimed I could calculate the average value of a set of words, but I defined that to mean "the average length of a word in the set", could you then argue that since the average value was not a word, then it is not actually an "average" value of those words?

Sorry if that was confusing, I am having trouble expressing this in words.

Comment: Yes, if you want an _average flooble_. No, if you want just an _average_ (in whatever way you defined it), not necessarily a flooble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal definition of average.  Where averages are usually mentioned you're working with at least the real numbers.  There's even a sort-of average taken in group theory, forgot what it was....  ah wait, here we go:

[Burnside's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)

So when something is labeled with the term average there is usually a "summation" operator, although this maybe some non-everyday arithmetic operator like set union for instance, and a final normalizing factor that you scale the sum by.

Comment: I see; I didn't realize "mean" was such a fuzzy concept. "Maximum" and "minimum" have concrete definitions based on $\geq$ and $\leq$, for example, but I guess the question I was *really* asking was if "mean" had a concrete definition and properties as well. Just to confirm, the answer to that is "no", correct? "Mean" is a fuzzy term that differs depending on context, as long as it somehow represents some concept of a center-y (not sure what word to use) value that is meaningful to whatever problem is being solved?

Comment: Yes, correct.  That's the way I see it but maybe an expert Category theorist could find an all-connecting generalization of "mean".  However I think that's akin to saying gravitational orbits are similar to electron orbits, so the relatedness of the two phenomena is not really interesting yet, unless you're from Sedona, AZ, where I live :D and everything is connected.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is the following, does it make sense to talk about the mean of $\{1,2,3,5\}$ *as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$*. The answer is no. There is no number in $\mathbb{N}$ that does what you want the mean to do.